# Azure Data factory: Copy Data from lookup to Blob

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a lookup activity which is querying from Salesforce. I want to store all the results into Blob. Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: which version of azure data factory have you?

Comment: V2 I believe. I mean i can directly use Copy activity but wanna do it for lookup.

Comment: Did you tried the wizard? is very easy to use and very intuitive!

Comment: Actually I already have a pipeline and this functionality should be integrated in it. Cant use the wizard. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please read this and give more context when asking.

Comment: @MartinEstebanZurita What was the thing you did not understand from the question mate? Essentially I want to use a copy activity after a lookup. Wasnt it apparent from the question?